# Cloud Functions with Real Time Notifications and Pub/Sub - What is endpoint url?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, push, google-cloud-pubsub, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to implement this example: [create rtdn](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready?hl=pt-br#configure-rtdn) of developer notifications, however, I use firebase, so I'll be using Cloud Functions to give onPublish in my topic subscriptions.

My question is as follows, the recommended for pub / sub notifications for Real Time Notifications is to use **push notifications**, since the pull is based on the assumption of the back end to exit, which does **not happen in Cloud Functions**, however, when clicking push on the Console, it asks for an "endpoint url", **where do I get this endpoint url from or how would I generate it**? In fact, even though I researched, I did not understand the reason for this.

Screenshoot example:

[image: Push]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make a push subscription yourself through the Pub/Sub console. If you go to ‘[Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)’, create one and set the trigger to be ‘Cloud Pub/Sub’ and then choose a topic, it will create a push subscription on your behalf. After that, whenever a message is published on that topic, your cloud function will be triggered.

The URL endpoint is used when you own an HTTP address that you want Pub/Sub to push messages to.

Comment: I will use this pub to have real time notifications, so not to create the pub / sub just by the cloud function, you have to create it before

Comment: Subscribe pub/sub to real time developer notifications